# Are configuration interaction (CI) and configuration interaction method (CI-method) the same thing?

Tags: quantum-chemistry

I am trying to study molecular quantum mechanics and I am quite confused because the material that I'm reading has a separate section called "Configuration interaction" and another separate section called "Configuration interaction calculations".

In the CI section, it is explained that in $H_2$-molecule, if the basis set consists of 1s-orbitals of the hydrogen atoms ($\phi_A$, $\phi_B$), the two electrons can occupy the molecular orbitals (MOs) according to four different configurations:

$1\sigma_g(1) 1\sigma_g(2)$

$2\sigma_u(1) 2\sigma_u(2)$

$1\sigma_g(1) 2\sigma_u(2)$

$2\sigma_u(1) 1\sigma_g(2)$

The last two configurations can form antisymmetric and symmetric linear combinations:

$\frac{1}{\sqrt2}(1\sigma_g(1) 2\sigma_u(2) - 2\sigma_u(1) 1\sigma_g(2))$

$\frac{1}{\sqrt2}(1\sigma_g(1) 2\sigma_u(2) + 2\sigma_u(1) 1\sigma_g(2))$

The four possible total wave functions are the first two configurations multiplied by spin wave function and the linear combinations multiplied by spin wave functions. The term symbols associated with these wave functions are  $^1\Sigma_g$, $^1\Sigma_g$, $^3\Sigma_u$, $^1\Sigma_u$, respectively. As you can see, two wave functions have the same symmetry, and as the internuclear distance $R \rightarrow \infty$, the states of the same symmetry converge to the same dissociation limit. This means that the energies of the states of the same symmetry never cross at any $R$ due to the non-vanishing matrix element between the states in the Hamiltonian. Due to the off-diagonal matrix elementrs, configurations of the same symmetry mix. This is called the Configuration interaction.

Now, the other section is the Configuration Interaction calculations, where it is explained that CI-method is a method to approximately solve the electronic SE. In CI-method, the exact wave function for any electronic state can be expressed as a linear combination of all possible n-electron Slater determinants arising from a complete set of spin orbitals. This is called the CI wave function. In practice, e.g. CISD is used, where only singly and doubly excited determinants are used in the calculation.

I kind of understand both of the things explained above, but I am very confused since I'm not sure if the two things explained above are the same thing? Or are they completely different topics but have the same name? Can someone explain, are these the same thing? Or is it that the CI-method just takes the Configuration interaction into account?

Comment: CI is within its limitations an exact theory. CISD is truncated and will have shortcomings. The latter is an approximation to the former. So the method and the theory are definitely not the same thing.